# AR A-frame Hide div when marker active

Tags: html, hide, augmented-reality, marker

There is a "scanning" graphic here that hides when you find the marker.
https://webxr.io/webar-playground/app/

How is that done? I have tried a bunch of different things with no luck. Maybe I am just not putting it in the correct place? Or need to call the action? Here is the last thing I tried:

```
'''
var m = document.querySelector("a-marker")
AFRAME.registerComponent('hide-on-scan', {
init: function () {

m.addEventListener("markerFound", (e)=>{
document.getElementsByTagName("HeaderText")[0].setAttribute("style", "display: none;");
})

m.addEventListener("markerLost", (e)=>{
document.getElementsByTagName("HeaderText")[0].setAttribute("style", "display: block;");
})
});
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out for those looking to do the same thing here's my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<style type="text/css">
#HeadText {
position: absolute;
top:0px;
left:50%;
z-index: 10000;
}
</style>
</head>

<body style='margin : 0px; overflow: hidden;'>
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.8.2/aframe.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/dev/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js"></script>

<a-scene embedded arjs='sourceType: webcam;'>

<div id="HeadText" style="visibility:visible;">
    <h1>test</h1>
</div>

<a-marker preset='hiro'>
    <a-box id="MyBox" position='0 0.5 0' material='opacity: 0.5;' color="red" ></a-box>
</a-marker>

<a-camera-static /> 
</a-scene>

</body>
<script  src="assets/script.js"></script>
</html>

</head>
<body>
```

And here is the script.js:

```
var m = document.querySelector("a-marker")
m.addEventListener("markerFound", (e)=>{
console.log("found")
document.getElementById("HeadText").style.visibility = "hidden";
    })

m.addEventListener("markerLost", (e)=>{
console.log("lost");
document.getElementById("HeadText").style.visibility = "visible";
})
```